# SSH Key Permission Denied

Tags: unix, ssh, vpn, digital-ocean, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up cloud hosting with [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-digitalocean-droplets).

Please skip to the **bold part** with asterisks (***) for the actual problem. Everything below here, above that part is background info.

I need to generate an RSA key pair, so I navigate to my `cd ~/.ssh/` directory, then:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I already have existing `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files, so when prompted:

> Enter file in which to save the key (/demo/.ssh/id_rsa):

I enter the following to create a new pair:

`~/.ssh/id_cloudhosting`

I'm then asked for a passphrase, which I simply press `return` for "no password":

> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):

I repeat the above for confirmation, and the final output looks as  follows (just a demo image):

[image]

Now that I have two new files, `id_cloudhosting` and `id_cloudhosting.pub` I need to copy the contents of the public file to my Digital Ocean hosting 'Add SSH console'. I do that like so:

`cat ~/.ssh/id_cloudhosting.pub`

Which returns the contents of the file:

```
ssh-rsa 
bUnChOFcOd3scrambledABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZnowIknowmy
ABCnextTIMEwontyouSINGwithmeHODOR demo@a
```

I paste the key into my hosting console and it saves successfully.

**The next step is where the permission issues start:** ****************

I need to ["spin up a new server"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-digitalocean-droplets) - step four from their docs. So I enter the following:

`cat ~/.ssh/id_worker.pub | ssh root@[my.hosting.ip.address] "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

Which should copy the public key as root to a newly created file called `authorized_keys`

This step never gets created because I'm immediately asked for a password to my host. I didn't ever create one! I pressed `return` (or enter) at that point, so I do the same when prompted, and get permission denied!

> root@[host.ip.address]'s password:
>
> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> root@[host.ip.address]'s password:
>
> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> root@[host.ip.address]'s password:
>
> Permission denied (publickey,password).

How can I rectify these permission denied issues?

**EDIT: FIX BELOW**

It seems as though, by using an unconventional (other than `id_rsa`) file, I needed to explicitly identify the file by doing the following:

`ssh root@droplet.ip.address -i /path/to/private_key_file`

...be sure not to use the public_key_file there. I am not connected to the server from my terminal. This is after destroying my previous droplet, creating a fresh one, with fresh key files, as @will-barnwell suggested

Comment: As the docs state, the `cat ... | ssh` command is only for adding SSH keys to a pre-existing droplet.  When you created `my.hosting.ip.address`, did you add any SSH keys at that time, and, if so, what were they?

Comment: I created the droplet with 1 key, `~/.oldSSH/id_oldSSH.pub` and added that. It was saved successfully, but when I try to access the server with `ssh root@[my.hosting.ip.address]` i got the same permission issues. So I figured its because I was not using the default `.ssh/` folder and used `.oldSSH/` instead. I have since removed that key, generated a new one inside `.ssh/` and ran into the same issues. To answer your question, my first go at this, I did not use the `cat ... | ssh` command

Comment: "I have since removed that key" — Do you mean that you deleted `~/.oldSSH/id_oldSSH` without first adding a different key to your droplet's `authorized_keys` file?  If so, you've locked yourself out of SSH access and need to fix this via the DigitalOcean console.

Comment: The original key `~/.oldSSH/id_oldSSH.pub` remains on my file system. I simply removed it from my droplet via the SSH Keys console found within `Settings > Security > SSH Keys` - Once removed, I generated a new key `~/.ssh/id_cloudhosting.pub` and pasted it in the SSH Keys console, then saved it successfully. I have yet to discover this `authorized_keys` file they speak about (maybe thats the problem), but I do have an existing `known_hosts` file that has been in my `.ssh/` directory for quite some time (believe it holds some info for github)

Comment: You can't add or remove keys from a droplet via the web console after it's been created; all you did was alter the set of keys available to you when creating a new droplet.  Your pre-existing droplet still requires `id_oldSSH` to log in, and that can only be changed by editing `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the droplet.

Comment: Perhaps our terminology is not aligned. I have not used the "web console" for anything as yet. I have used the SSH Keys (console/widget/component) to simply add and remove keys. Everything else was done on my terminal. Your update on what the SSH Keys 'widget' is actually used for is extremely helpful. I have since tried signing into the actual "web console" and apparently need a login for that as well. Could I simply blow away this droplet and create a new one from scratch? I really appreciate your help here @jwodder

Comment: "Web console" was probably the wrong term to use there; I just meant https://cloud.digitalocean.com.  Yes, as long as your droplet doesn't contain anything you're attached to, you can just destroy it and create a new one.

Comment: It's never clear if you had ssh access to the server, have you ever logged in successfully? There is a greaty deal of information in these comments which should be in the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have followed the linked guide up to and through Step Three, when you create a new server from their Web UI use the "Add SSH Keys" option and select the key you added to your account previously.

> When actually spinning up a new server, select the keys that you would
>   like installed on your server from the "Create a Droplet" screen. You
>   can select as many keys as you like:
>
> Once you click on the SSH key, the text saying, "Your
>   root password will be emailed to you" will disappear, and you will not
>   receive an email confirmation that your server has been created.

The command you were using was to add an ssh key to pre-existing server. Judging from the above quote I bet the password that you are being prompted for is in your email.

---

### Why?

When you create a server on Digital Ocean ( or really most cloud hosting services ) a root password is automatically generated for you, **unless** you set the server up with an authorization key.

Using key authentication is definitely a good security choice, but make sure to read the instructions carefully, don't just copy/paste commands and expect it all to work out.

---

**EDIT:** OP's comments on the question have shed additional light on the matter.

New Advice: Blow your server away and set up the SSH keys as suggested, your server is probably unusable if it is not accepting your old SSH key and is prompting you for a password you don't have.

Be careful messing around with your last auth key, add a new one before removing an old one.

Comment: I followed the steps thoroughly. I actually replicate each step here in this very question. I haven't received an email, because I used SSH keys as shown above. You receive an email when you do not use SSH keys, as explained in your quote. The only modifications I have made to the guide, was creating new rsa files `id_cloudhosting.pub` as opposed to the default `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Your question followed steps 1-3 and then, "I need to "spin up a new server" - step four from their docs. So I enter the following:

`cat ~/.ssh/id_worker.pub | ssh root@[my.hosting.ip.address] "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"` " There was no indication of what really happened, as revealed in subsequent comments. I based this answer on your original question.